# Replacing text with Regex

Tags: regex

I have a text file that contains a data dump from a database. 
This is space delimited and as stupid as this sounds, this is what I have to work with. 
The problem that I have is that there's a free textfield that includes newlines.

So what I would try to do is
replace every \r  that is **not** followed by an id that matches the following pattern [0-9]{6}

Comment: Looks like a job for negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tool you are working with support regular expression with look-around assertions, you could use

```
\r(?!\d{6})
```